# Screen command for Ansible

Tags: ansible, gnu-screen

Is there anyway I can use the screen command with ansible?
Would be great if we can screen logs while installing applications to keep full logs.

Comment: when you say screen command, do you mean by screen multi-plexer or output the logs on the screen?

Comment: Yes screen multi-plexer

Answer (score 0):

You can use shell module and run screen with "bash -c", and add | tee command to write all output to file. Or use screen with parameter "-Logfile file"

```
ansible -i ${inventory} -m shell -a "screen -mdSA screenname bash -c 'ls -lah | tee /tmp/screenname-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log.txt'"
```